# EXCEL formula variable pricing structure

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Cell B3 equals a number of Item 1 purchased with a variable pricing structure.
I have a formula that **works great** and creates an accurate $ cost

```
=IF(B3<5,7188*B3,IF(B3<=19,(B3-4)*4788+28752,IF(B3>19,(B3-19)*3588+100572)))
```

Items #1 purchased:   1-4=$599 per mth, 5-19=$399 per mth, 20+=$299 per mth

This allows me to have a variable total cost based upon the number purchased.

Cell B4 is the second item with the following price structure:
1-4=$524 per mth, 5-19=$349 per mth, 20+=$249 per mth

My problem is that if they purchase some of the second B4 the cost is variable like above, but you start using the second values **after the first purchased items reach the 1-4,5-19,20+ threshold**

Second formula for the second item purchased is currently (**but not working**):

```
=IF(B4<5,6288*B4,IF(B4<=19,(B4-4)*4188+25152,IF(B4>19,(B4-19)*2988+87972)))
```

If I sell 6 of the first, it is 4*$599*12mth + 2*$399*12mth
and 2 of the second item, we have passed the 4 threshold, so the second item would now be sold at B4*349*12mths

I cannot figure out a formula that will work.

Comment: How does $599 per mth reflect in the formula? How do the numbers `7188` and `4788+28752` and `3588+100572` relate to $599 and $399 and $299?

Comment: @teylyn  Divide them by 12.  Apparently `mth` = `month` and he is returning a yearly price.

Comment: That is correct, but you can forget those 4788+28752 & 3588+100572  numbers.   I basically need to understand a way to do the following.
B3 is the number of item #1 purchased
B4 is the number of item #2 purchased

Comment: Think of this as a subscription with a economies of scale pricing.

B3 is the # of item 1 subscriptions
There is a monthly maint charge based upon # subscribers
1-4=$599 per month, 5-19=$399 per month, 20+=$299 per month

B4 is the # of item 2 subscriptions
1-4=$524 per month, 5-19=$349 per month, 20+=$249 per month

The trick of the question is that if they buy 7 item #1s and 25 item #2s
4*$599*12mth + 3*$399*12mth   then  + 12*$349*12mth + 13*$249*12mth = $102,216

=IF(B4<5,6288*B4,IF(B4<=19,(B4-4)*4188+25152,IF(B4>19,(B4-19)*2988+87972)))

I cannot figure the switch from item1 to 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EXCEL Formula economies of scale calculation](http://superuser.com/questions/1027292/excel-formula-economies-of-scale-calculation).  The question was resubmitted with slightly clearer wording and answered.

Comment: @fixer1234   Yes - you gave me a perfect solution - Thank you Fixer1234